# closePath() Moving Polygon

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, jsfiddle

The following code below is what is needed to make a simple triangle. I want to keep the triangle in that exact position and add this to my canvas.

```js
can = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(1, 20);
ctx.lineTo(20, 100);
ctx.lineTo(70, 100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

If you run the code below, the triangle is there for a split second and then disappears. I need it to stay there along with the three equations. I created the function path(); in effort to keep the triangle positioned in the upper left corner. I am not sure how to keep the triangle there and do all of this.

```html
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.09.25.combined.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#gameCanvas {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
</style>
<div class="canvasHolder1">
  <div id="eqn1"> 3+3=<input type="text" id="q1" />
    </div>
  <div id="eqn2"> 3+2=<input type="text" id="q2" />
    </div>
  <div id="eqn3"> 5+2=<input type="text" id="q3" />
    </div>
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="600">Not supported</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">

var m=1;

  var stage = new createjs.Stage("gameCanvas");
  var obj=[];
 
can = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(1, 20);
ctx.lineTo(20, 100);
ctx.lineTo(70, 100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
function startGame() {
   
    obj[1] = new createjs.DOMElement(document.getElementById(`eqn${1}`));
    obj[2] = new createjs.DOMElement(document.getElementById(`eqn${2}`));
    stage.addChild(obj[1]);
    stage.addChild(obj[2]);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    function handleTick(event){
    drop(1);
    drop(2);
    path();
    stage.update();
    }
}
 function drop(i){
      obj[1].x =40;
      obj[1].y =50;
      obj[2].x =300;
      obj[2].y =50;
 }
function path(){
ctx.x=1;
ctx.y=1;
}
</script>
<body onload="startGame();">
    <div >
  <canvas>This browser or document mode doesn't support canvas object.</canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have two `canvas` elements in your document. The `gameCanvas` is outside of your `<body>` tag, which causes the bug. Move the `canvasHolder1` div and the `<script>` to the `<body>` tag. Order the `<script>` as last. The reason for this is that the browser reads (and executes) the document from top to bottom.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Are you saying move everything `<div class="canvasHolder1">
  <div id="eqn1"> 3+3=<input type="text" id="q1" />
    </div>
  <div id="eqn2"> 3+2=<input type="text" id="q2" />
    </div>
  <div id="eqn3"> 5+2=<input type="text" id="q3" />
    </div>
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="600">Not supported</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">` to the <body> tag? I'm not sure what you mean by body tag here as well. What is the body tag? Do you mean the start game function?

Comment: I'm just not quite sure what you mean

Comment: The `<body>...</body>` element represents all the content on the page. So your canvas and content elements should be in there. [See here for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure) However, this does not seem to be the reason for your bug. When I walked through your code I noticed that the canvas does seem to render properly whenever I remove the `stage.update();` line. What does that line do?

Comment: I think that is what reiterates the startGame function. It is used for the ticker element

Comment: Here is a tool that can be useful to validate your code: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Math Game</title>
  <script src="//code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.09.25.combined.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="startGame();">
  <div class="canvasHolder1">
    <div id="eqn1"> 3+3=<input type="text" id="q1" /></div>
    <div id="eqn2"> 3+2=<input type="text" id="q2" /></div>
    <div id="eqn3"> 5+2=<input type="text" id="q3" /></div>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="200">Not supported</canvas>
  </div>

  <script>
    var stage = new createjs.Stage("gameCanvas");
    var can = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    var obj = [];

    function drawTriangle() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(1, 20);
      ctx.lineTo(20, 100);
      ctx.lineTo(70, 100);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    function startGame() {
      obj[1] = new createjs.DOMElement(document.getElementById("eqn1"));
      obj[1].x = 40;
      obj[1].y = 50;
      stage.addChild(obj[1]);

      obj[2] = new createjs.DOMElement(document.getElementById("eqn2"));
      obj[2].x = 300;
      obj[2].y = 50;
      stage.addChild(obj[2]);

      stage.update();
      drawTriangle();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can see I created a new function `drawTriangle` it will be called at the end of your `startGame` that way the triangle is the last item drawn in the canvas.

I'm not sure why you needed the `Ticker` so I remove it, same with the other functions, they did not make much sense to me, no need for what you are trying to accomplish at the moment.

---

Now to your problem... in my implementation I have the drawTriangle as the last action in the startGame, but if we change the order, to something like this:

```
      drawTriangle();
      stage.update();
```

The triangle disappears!

My educated guess is that `stage.update()` clears the entire canvas and draws what it "knows" the triangle drawing is happening outside the stage so we need to always draw it after.

Looking at the code documentation for `update`:
https://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/files/easeljs_display_Stage.js.html#l349
there is an if statement  `if (this.autoClear) {` that does exactly what we are seeing in your sample, and the default value of autoClear is true:
https://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html#property_autoClear

---

Also worth pointing out... there is a native createjs way to draw lines:

- https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_moveTo
- https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_lineTo

There is nothing wrong with your approach, you are using both createjs and directly drawing in the canvas via `getContext("2d")` you just have to plan accordingly, but my recommendation, if there is a native approach I would stick with that, here is a sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Math Game</title>
  <script src="//code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.09.25.combined.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="startGame();">
  <div class="canvasHolder1">
    <div id="eqn1"> 3+3=<input type="text" id="q1" /></div>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="160">Not supported</canvas>
  </div>

  <script>
    function startGame() {
      var stage = new createjs.Stage("gameCanvas");
      var eqn1 = new createjs.DOMElement(document.getElementById("eqn1"));
      eqn1.x = eqn1.y = 50;
      stage.addChild(eqn1);
      
      var triangle = new createjs.Shape();
      triangle.graphics.beginStroke("black")
      triangle.graphics.moveTo(1, 20);
      triangle.graphics.lineTo(20, 100);
      triangle.graphics.lineTo(70, 100);
      triangle.graphics.lineTo(1, 20);
      stage.addChild(triangle);

      stage.update();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for the thorough answer! This helps a lot.

Comment: @WilliamGarske glad it was helpful ... Ye I took some time to research `createjs` a bit more, in your own answers remember you are not just answering the question, but giving anyone in the future that might a similar issue a hint of how to solve it ...

Comment: @WilliamGarske which approach you like better? the native triangle looks easy enough

Comment: I like both of them! The first way looks cleaner. I like how you mention the the stage.update(); thing matters with how the order goes. That being said, I think I prefer the second way because I like the way that the var triangle is being added to the stage and know exactly what it is called